# Discord.js DND Dice Roll Input Change Number

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've made a "working" dice roll function on my bot. Works fine for what I need, but was wondering how I could make it so depending on what is said in discord it rolls.

So saying !rolld6 would use 6 in var response instead of 20.

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes("!rolld20")) {
const ayy = client.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === "diceroll");
var response = [Math.floor(Math.random() * ((20 - 1) + 1) + 1)];
            message.channel.send(`${ayy}` + `Rolling.`)
                .then(msg => {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        msg.edit(`${ayy}` + `Rolling..`)
                    }, 1000);
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        msg.edit(`${ayy}` + `Rolling...`)
                    }, 2000)
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        msg.edit(`${ayy}` + `Rolling....`)
                    }, 3000)    
            setTimeout(function() {
                        
            msg.edit(`${ayy}` + " Rolled... " + response + " " + `${ayy}`).then().catch(console.error)  
                    }, 4000)    
            
                })


return;
}
```

Not even sure what I would search to figure this out so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression instead of `.includes`, and then extract the digits after the `d` to randomize.

You don't need to subtract 1, then add 1 right after that - those cancel out, nor do you need to put the result into an array - interpolating just the random number generated into the message will work fine.

```
const match = message.content.match(/!rolld(\d+)/i);
if (match) {
    const die = match[1];
    const response = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * die);    
    const ayy = client.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === "diceroll");
```

Comment: Perfect that works great, how would I go about adding another match by using !rollXdX so basically acting as if rolling 2 dice then? A new const?

Comment: Add another capture group to the regular expression - if you want to permit numbers before the `d`, put the same sort of capture group there, and then the number of dies will be in the first capture group, and the die sides will be in the second capture group, and you can repeat the random process for the number of dies requested.

Comment: I've sorted it but realised that it uses the same randomise die number for however dice you roll, probably need a for loop but not sure on how really? 

say you roll 10 dice, with random number 5, they all roll at 5 but they should be random

```const match3 = message.content.match(/!roll(\d+)d(\d+)/i);
if (match3) {
    const dice = match3[1];
    const die = match3[2];
    const response = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * die); 
    var response3 = [Math.floor(Number(response) * Number(dice))]; 
      
    const ayy = client.emojis.cache.find(emoji => emoji.name === "diceroll");```

Comment: `for (const die of dice) { const response = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * die);` etc - calculate the random values inside the loop